# Trying to get User (email) after google oath with python ->

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

i am trying to get the email address of the current user after oauth.
I have found a solution on the web:

```
def get_user_info():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
  'client_secrets.json',
  scopes=['openid',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'])

  flow.run_local_server()
  credentials = flow.credentials

  # service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

  # Optionally, view the email address of the authenticated user.
  user_info_service = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
  user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
  user_email = user_info['email']
  return user_email
```

First it was working on one machine, then i tried it on another:

First the Authentification pop up comes up and is satified:

*The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window.*

On the second run however i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakob/PycharmProjects/pywhatsapp2/main.py", line 313, in <module>
    user_email = get_user_info()
  File "/home/jakob/PycharmProjects/pywhatsapp2/main.py", line 290, in get_user_info
    flow.run_local_server()
  File "/home/jakob/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 499, in run_local_server
    local_server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 154, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

The error “Address is already in use” is thrown because the server that deals with oauth cannot be started because you already have another server currently running on that address. What it seems it happened is that in your first run you started a server and never stopped it, so when you tried to run it again, the server could not start because the address was already being used. Normally you want to always have a server running instead of always having to start one specifically for oauth in your case.

If the address is being used by another server try changing the port number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i guess that you are right. In the same script i am authenticating separately with gsheets and with gspread for different tasks. While this for itself runs stable the 3rd flow which i use is either "one too much" or i guess that the get_user_info flow's server does not terminate after the session... How could i verify that?

Comment: Try to ping te server at localhost:8080 but the server should already be closed by the time you ping it since it runs by itself. My other guess is that the service right before gmail my be slower in closing the server so it blocks the default port (8080). Can you verify by passing a different port inside each of your service functions? e.g: run_local_server(host=‘localhost’, port=8081)

Comment: Hello Andrei, thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately trying the host/port option did not overcome the error